# Translating "整理し"

Tags: meaning

> そうした時に、弊事務所は、まず整理し何が問題かを可視化します。

Trying to translate this, for now I have

> At such times, our firm first organizes and visualizes what the problem is.

But I'm not comfortable with the idea that the firm "organizes [...] what the problem is". Should the idea of "整理し" be on its own? For example:

> At such times, our firm first organizes the facts and visualizes what the problem is.

I know "the facts" is not in the Japanese, but it seems assumed in the context of facing a problematic situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of complementing it with 'the facts' is practically fine.

In Japanese, 整理する can be intransitive and considering it as on its own is one possibility. Another possibility is to assume some implicit object. As I said, 'the facts' is fine, but in Japanese it is idiomatic to say 問題を整理する, meaning analyzing the problems into factors. So, though virtually the same as your translation, it more literally means 'we analyze and visualize the problem(s)'.